# OS X Yosemite Curl errors

Tags: macos, curl, ssl, osx-yosemite

I am trying to use curl on Yosemite and I keep getting the following errors:

```
01-09-14 17:49:45> curl https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-manpages-2.1.0.tar.gz
curl: (51) SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)
```

I know I can add `-k` to the curl to make it download, but I think there is something bigger that I need to fix.  The biggest issue is when trying to update Homebrew packages.

I also have this in my bash_profile

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-bundle.crt
```

and i just downloaded the ca-bundle.crt from http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

EDIT:  Also on a the guest user account on my laptop the curl works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out

```
export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-bundle.crt
```

was the problem for some reason.  Removed that from my bash_profile and restarted a few times and everything works fine now.

Comment: I had the same problem, but didn't have that line in my `~/.bash_profile`, so I was a bit confused. After digging around, it turns out that the line was in `~/.nix-profile/etc/profile.d/nix.sh`, which the [Nix Package Manager](http://nixos.org/nix/) adds to `~/.bash_profile` so it can use a custom version of curl.