# Symfony 2.7, PayumBundle, Paypal

Tags: php, symfony, curl, paypal

after almost two years of using stackoverflow for solving my issues it's the first time i didn't found a solution, so my first post.

I'm currently making an traineeship and i have to implement a paypal payment on a project running on symfony 2.7.

I choose the payumBundle (it's seems to me to be the most updated bundle).

Working in the sandbox of paypal was working, but when i want to test with live credentials, it's crash.

My composer.json for payum :

`"payum/payum-bundle": "1.0.3", 
"payum/payum": "1.1.4", 
"payum/core": "1.3.0", 
"php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1.0"`

My config :
`payum: 
security: 
token_storage: AppBundle\Entity\Announce\PaymentToken: { doctrine: orm } 
storages: AppBundle\Entity\Announce\PaymentAnnounce: { doctrine: orm } 
gateways: 
paypal_express_checkout: paypal_express_checkout_nvp: 
username: "%paypal_username%" 
password: "%paypal_password%" 
signature: "%paypal_signature%" 
sandbox: "%payment_test%"`

When i'm testing with sandbox parameters (with my personal account it's working).
My problem is that when i want to go "live" it doesn't work anymore.
I have access to a business account on paypal so i have credentials (username, password, signature) for the api and i turn sandbox to false (it's the right think to do no?). But then i've got an "cURL error 51: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)" on payment/capture.

I have search for a long time and i don't find any working solutions.
I have to admit i'm not sure if it's a problem with the bundle or with anything of my environnement (Mac El Capitan, PHP 5.6.23 by Liip, curl 7.47.1, it's not me creating the environment for coding) apparently php was installed with http://php-osx.liip.ch/ and so openssl and curl are in it and i don't find how to update them (curl, openssl, libs)). Do you have any links?

For example when i try brew upgrade curl it's say that curl is not installed by curl is accessible in the terminal

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613977/os-x-yosemite-curl-errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You use Guzzle6 and it made me made me think of a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok) I had with curl and certification with guzzle. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16495053/4248549) is for Windows but comments stated that it worked OSX.

***Answer:***
*You need just to set cacert.pem to curl.cainfo.
Since PHP 5.3.7 you could do:*

```
download https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and save it somewhere.
update php.ini -- add curl.cainfo = "PATH_TO/cacert.pem"
```

*Otherwise you will need to do the following for every cURL resource:*

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "PATH_TO/cacert.pem");
```